# Building a secured app with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security

Building an application where security is critical.

Are there any recommendations, readings (books / blogs) or gems that can help?

Need to protect DB data at all costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) is a Rails Security Scanner that can spot some low-hanging fruit of security issues and/or practices which may impact security. There's also an [OWASP Ruby on Rails security document](https://www.owasp.org/images/2/26/Owasp-rails-security.pdf) you can review (FYI, it is a few years old but many security best practices are general enough to at least get some benefit from). Further, there's an [official portion to the rails project](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) regarding security. Lastly, here's a [Ruby on Rails Cheat Sheet from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet) regarding security and it does cover some database practices.

You'll also want to think about [web application firewalls](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Best_Practices%3a_Use_of_Web_Application_Firewalls) and [SQL proxies](http://www.greensql.com/). Lots of options to layer security. Be sure to keep your Rails software up to date whenever possible and if in doubt, have a third party company do a security audit of the code and or application.